# Android: Google SSO - OAuth or AccountManager? Or both?

Tags: android, oauth, google-reader, accountmanager

After reading all sorts of Stackoverflow postings and various documentation including some on http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ site I feel utterly confused. So can someone explain to me the best way of achieving the following:

1. Let user to approve my app. I don't really care if this is done by accessing their registered Google account in accounts/settings and approving the app (preferred way) or by calling Google OAuth authentication page
2. Obtain the authentication token that can be used to communicate with Google Reader

Another point of confusion for me - I was able to approve my app using AccountManager and get auth token from it but it won't work with Google Reader. So how to balance Account information from the AccountManager and OAuth? Do I still need to do anything with OAuth after I get approved by user in AccountManager settings?

Code example would be nice but I look more for some clear explanation on how all these pieces are related to each other

Comment: What do you mean by "approve" your app? Do you seek to use their identity in your app (OpenID) or have your app access your user's data with Google (OAuth) ?

Comment: Fair question. In this particular case I want to be able to sign user into their Google reader account using their phone's registered Google account. Alternatively (if that is not possible) I would not mind (but prefer not to) redirect user initially to Google OAuth app approval page.

Comment: The actual retrieval of information from the Google Reader account is done by the remote server, the app only needs to pass the appropriate authentication token

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The account manager lets you get authentication tokens for different services. There are different concrete implementation under the hood: ClientLogin, OAuth, etc. To get it to work with, say, Google Reader, you need to pass the appropriate token type. For ClientLogin, those are short string like "ah" (App Engine) and "reader" (Google Reader). For OAuth, they are scopes, as defined by each service. So, what are you passing as the `authTokenType` parameter?

Getting the token is asynchronous, since it may involve network access. If there is a cached token, it will be returned right away, if valid. The flow is not that complicated, see the link above for the pretty picture. Once you get the token, you put it in the appropriate header, and use the API as per the spec.

Comment: As I said I would prefer signing user with their existing Google account. Is there any documentation on these "short strings" that outlines what is supported?

Comment: The correct term is actually  'service name'. This is not a complete list, but here are most: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#clientlogin. For general info about authenticating to Google services, you might want to start here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/. Android's AccountManger is just a frontend to those.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I'm accepting your answer since I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest at this point

Comment: I think the problem I'm having now with this approach is that Reader still has no official API. So I can't specify my API key using Google concole and can only get read-only access. So I'm creating another question for this

Comment: There is this, but it's not official: http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/ This might also be helpful, it has some Android specific code, but, AFAIK, no support for Reader: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Answer (score 4):

Here's an Android training class on AccountManager that might help:

http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Also, using AccountManager with Google Reader is currently the only preferred way of doing this. Directing your users to a login page with a WebView is not very secure and using a browser isn't supported by Google APIs as far as I know (I'm also not sure if Reader uses OAuth2 or not).